# Isn't React's immutable element creation and rendering mechanism terribly inefficient?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am not a React developer, but I am implementing a similar State and Props management infrastructure in another language. While reading about [React's state management and rendering mechanism](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html), I came across this quote

> React elements are immutable. Once you create an element, you can’t change its children or attributes. An element is like a single frame in a movie: it represents the UI at a certain point in time.

If I understand correctly, every time the parent component's state changes, its children's render methods are called (if their Props was affected) and these child components are recreated and (re)rendered.

Isn't this terribly inefficient, especially if the child components involve complex computations, visualizations, etc? Is there a mechanism in React to create the components once, but update (not recreate) only the necessary parts as the states change?

Comment: If you have something that is computationally expensive, you `useMemo` or `useRef` it.

Comment: Just because a component re-renders, does not mean that it needs to update the DOM (which is where the real performance issues would take place).

There are also ways to prevent a component from re-rendering all together if its' props don't change by using `React.memo(YourComponent)`

Comment: There is a lot of optimalizations (diffing/reconcilation ( https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html ), fiber) in react, f.e. react deosn't need to rerender any of view elements/components when its props not changed - render must be called but can skip processing of many subelements, reuse their state/rendered form. Componentizing is cheap in react.

Answer (score 2):

Well, that's the whole point of why we use React.

Have you heard about [Virtual DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html#what-is-the-virtual-dom)? Virtual DOM is simply a memory instance that saves the exact replica of the real DOM.

When there is a prop/state update, it does not re-render the whole thing, but only re-renders the UI parts that are affected.

So, it's very efficient and to see how they do it, you can check the source code [here](https://github.com/facebook/react).